# CruiseControl.NET and Clearcase configuration

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, clearcase, config

I'm having problems simply configuring the server for CruiseControl.NET.  I am using the source block that is given by ThoughtWorks to set it up, but I cannot seem to get it to be error-free.  I am pretty new to all this and some sort of direction would be fantastic.

1. Does anyone use this combination?
2. Do you have a `ccnet.config` file I can look at?

This is what does not work for me:

```
<cruisecontrol>
  <project name="test">
      <sourcecontrol type="clearCase">
        <exec>batch file</exec>
        <viewPath>path_name</viewPath>
        <branch>main</branch>
        <autoGetSource>false</autoGetSource>
        <useLabel>true</useLabel>
        <useBaseline>false</useBaseline>
        <projectVobName>vob_name</projectVobName>
        <viewName>projecy_name</viewName>
        <executable>cleartool.exe</executable>
        <timeout>50000</timeout>
      </sourcecontrol>
  </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have no direct experience with [this kind of setup](http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Rational%20ClearCase%20Source%20Control%20Block.html), but if you are using the `<projectVobName>` tag, that means:

- you are declaring a pvob (project vob used only in UCM to store project, stream, activities and components, all UCM data)
- your view (with the root directory referenced in `<viewPath>`) must be an UCM view.

All the other path elements (like 'executable') should reference an absolute path (and not just "`cleartool.exe`")