# Exception with CC .Net 1.6.789.1 - Cannot Start process because a file name has not been provided

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, clearcase

I had CC .NET 1.4.4 previously and everything was working fine. I
upgraded it to 1.6.789.1 and now and I get below exception in the log
file at `Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\Private Branch
\Artifacts\buildlogs` (I use clear case, but I guess that doesn't
matter, just FYI.)

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this, as I
spent enough time on this.

```
<build date="2012-03-16 15:31:19" buildtime="00:00:00"
buildcondition="ForceBuild" />
 <exception><![CDATA[System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start
process because a file name has not been provided.
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Util.ProcessExecutor.RunnableProcess.StartProcess()
  at
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Util.ProcessExecutor.RunnableProcess.Run()
  at
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Util.ProcessExecutor.Execute(ProcessInfo
processInfo)
  at
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo
processInfo)
  at
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ClearCase.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult
from, IIntegrationResult to)
  at
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.FilteredSourceControl.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult
from, IIntegrationResult to)
  at
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModificationsWithLogging(ISourceControl
sc, IIntegrationResult from, IIntegrationResult to)
  at
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.QuietPeriod.GetModifications(ISourceControl
sourceControl, IIntegrationResult lastBuild, IIntegrationResult
thisBuild)
  at
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.GetModifications(IIntegrationResult
from, IIntegrationResult to)
  at
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest
request)]]></exception>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Comment: Please provide your project configuration, or at least the source control block.

Answer (score 0):

Using CC with ClearCase can matter (for instance when [used with CCRC](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/continuousintegrationrationalclearcaseremoteclient/), the ClearCase Remote Client), if the update process of your snapshot view (or your web view in the case of CCRC) has any issue to complete.

<sup>(speculation:)</sup>  
Considering `ClearCase.GetModifications` is called, I suppose the name of the view is no longer provided, maybe because the CC process used to deduce said name from the current view directory (`cleartool lsview -cview`). If that CC process launches from the wrong directory (ie one *outside* of the ClearCase view), it would no longer be able to get back the right ClearCase view name.

Comment: The build is not even going till the step of updating the SnapShot view, it's not even kicking off my build Visual Build script. Below is the complete log file.

Comment: Sorry, i guess i can't upload the complete log file here. The build is not even showing up on CCTray once i kick it off, it just blows off with the above error.

Comment: @Maddy123 I believe this is the very first attempt to get the history (ie updating the view) which triggers the error.

Comment: iam able to update the view manually on clear case (not CCRC). I followed the above error trace and the error is at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() which returns true if process resource is started and false if no new process. This Start() method also throws an exception when 'No file name was specified in the System.Diagnostics.Process.StartInfo'. What file name is it looking for is confusing.

Comment: i uninstalled CC.NET 1.6 and installed 1.5, it works fine. Again i installed 1.6, but, with 1.6 iam facing the above issue. Its so obscure and frustracting, there is no reason for it to not run with 1.6.

Comment: @Maddy123 I suppose there is some kind of incompatibility between CC.Net (with its dependencies, see http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Install) and ClearCase.

Comment: Thanks VonC, I removed ClearCase (SourceControl) lines from CC config file and the build runs fine with 1.6. Now, I have to look into what's in ClearCase is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the fix for this issue. Thanks VonC for throwing some light on it and it was one of your older post that helped me fix this.

With CC.Net 1.4 and 1.5 i never had `<executable>` parameter under `<sourcecontrol>` section, but after looking at the following thread - [CruiseControl.NET and Clearcase configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240950/cruisecontrol-net-and-clearcase-configuration), i thought of using the full path of cleartoo.exe file as given below and it fixed the problem, build ran fine. It looks like for CC.NET 1.6 mentioning the full path of the source control exe is mandatory.

```
<executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Rational\ClearCase\bin\cleartool.exe</executable>
```